# Flask_APP environment variable not found

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner to Flask and I ran into some errors. about how I did not provide the Flask_APP environment variable:

```
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

I have this error with flask when I try and run my flask code. My code was working at first but then when I tried running it again it had this problem. I searched everywhere for help but I could only find ones about powershell. I'm currently using Ubuntu. Thank you!

Comment: could you provide what you tried to run, and what is your project structure?

Comment: I tried to run FLASK_APP=project.py      flask run

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to run a flask app using the flask command in the terminal, you need to set an environment variable in that terminal. For example, if your app is created in `my_app.py`, then you need to execute the following in your terminal:

```
export FLASK_APP=my_app.py
```

If you restart the terminal at any point you will need to re-export this variable.

You can check if it is set in your current terminal using:

```
echo $FLASK_APP
```

which will show nothing if unset or `my_app.py` if set as above.

Comment: Thank you very much! But now it shows this error.                                                            File "/home/mark/Desktop/folder/atom.py", line 3
    ​
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: That looks like a separate error. I would check in "atom.py" for any weird characters you might have. If you're still stuck: open a new question with the code so someone can help you out

Answer (score 0):

Once in your project directory run the command below will solve your problem

`flask --app app.py db init`

Where `app.py` is your flask application file name.